# Print preview for SSRS reports with sub report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report, which has a Sub Report. The reports works with the following logic:

> 1. The report has a detail row.
> 2. For each row, the report checks for data in the subreport.

The report is working in the Report View, but when i click the print preview, it vomits with an exception. Here is an image of the report in REPORT VIEW:

[image]

Here the image of the exception i get:
[image]

Any suggestions on to how to fix this issue?

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the sub-report into a rectangle (not textbox) and change the KeepTogether property of the rectangle to False.